# Display header even if <apex:pageBlockTable> is passed an empty List

Tags: visualforce, fieldsets

Is there a way to render the column headers of a  even if the passed list is empty? I have the field labels already in place as I am iterating over a Fieldset.

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!rows}" var="row">

            <apex:repeat value="{!fields}" var="field">

                <apex:column headerValue="{!field.Label}">
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe the problem is that you are binding to the data, which, when rendered with no results, is not there to reference.

Normally, without a field set you would bind to something in metadata. For instance like this:

```
<!-- meta describe example
<apex:column ... headerValue="{!$ObjectType.MyObj__c.fields.Field__c.label}"/>
<!-- custom label example
<apex:column ... headerValue="{!$Label.CustomLabelName}"/>
```

The describe example will simply pick up the label property of the field that you set when you defined it. The custom label example does need to be defined by going to *Create > Custom Labels* in the setup menu.

Using a fieldset, however, you need something more dynamic. Initially I tried the following:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Account.Contacts}" var="c">
  <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Contact.FieldSets.SetOfFields}" var="field">
    <apex:column value="{!c[field]}" headerValue="{!c[field].label}"/>
  </apex:repeat>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

In this way, I got no header label with my empty list of contacts.

But if I changed the header value as follows:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Account.Contacts}" var="c">
  <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Contact.FieldSets.SetOfFields}" var="field">
    <!--  THE headerValue BELOW IS THE DIFFERENCE ----v -->
    <apex:column value="{!c[field]}" headerValue="{!field.label}"/>
  </apex:repeat>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

This notation is referencing the metadata directly, and in this instance, with an empty list, I see my header labels.

[image]

Comment: I already use the FieldSetMembers 'field' Label for the header values instead of the empty lists 'row'. So this doesn't work.

Comment: What you describe in your question as the problem seems to be what I'm solving. Can you share a screen shot of the undesired behavior for clarification?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of deleting my question I decided to "answer" it. It did not work for another reason. The fieldset was not found when the list is empty as the code which fetches the fieldset relies on having at least one SObject in the list.

Comment: So it is driven by the way the Apex code fetches the fieldset? If so, that would be valuable to see in your question and in your answer.